# data loss due to a lot of requests , angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

im sending requests to server , first time for getting names
second time for getting info for these names
the problem is if i received 270 names at first time
and returned with 270 requests to get data for these 270 names , i get about 110 or less of them !!
im using promises for the job , each request is a promise .
i tried with setTimeout function to make a delay between requests
it doesnt work .
i tried also return a new promise if the request fails to send the failed request back again to the server and get data
but it doesn't make sense ...
what should i do ?

sample code

```
var Orderbook = function (name) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    bitmanager.getorderbook({ market: name, type: 'sell' }, function (data, err) {
        if (err) {
            sleep(2000, name).then(() => {
                console.error("failed .... go back");
                return Orderbook(name);// console.error(err);
            });
        }else
        resolve(data.result);
    });
});
```

};

Comment: How does your sleep function work? Do you control the back end also?

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: im using angularjs 1 , the sleep function is simply a promise resolves parameter after specific time .

Comment: im using api , so i dont have the back end to control it ...